# How to restrict user to access ".htaccess, web.config and mix-manifest.json" file from public folder through url?

Tags: php, laravel

How to restrict user to access ".htaccess, web.config and mix-manifest.json" file from public folder through url ?
Or Is it okay to keep it open for users?
One of the method i tried to block from url is

```
Route::get('/mix-manifest.json',function(){
    abort(404);
});
```

Also tried placing

```
<Files web.config>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>
```

in .htaccess Nothing worked.

But i might actually need this .
I am trying to restrict user to access sensitive files like .htaccess, web.config present inside the public folder through url.

Comment: Anyone please ? Got stuck in the same problem.

Comment: mix-manifest.json is generally ok to keep open. .htaccess is usually blocked from the default apache rules (and web.config from the default IIS rules I think) so I think it's just a matter of deleting the file you don't need to use (e.g. delete web.config if you use apache). Using a route to restrict access won't work because PHP only handles the request if the file does not exist on the files system